# Selenium: getting the latest HTML code after external modification to the web page

Tags: python, html, selenium-webdriver

I have a web page that is modified externally. For example, new text is written to text boxes, checkmarks are checked, etc. I would imagine that these changes are reflected in the HTML code of the web page. If so, I would like to use `Selenium` to retrieve the most modified HTML of the web page that encompass the changes.

I have tried using `driver.page_source` but it seems like it's returning the default HTML code (before any changes). I have also tried `driver.execute_script("return document.documentElement.outerHTML;")` but no luck. Wondering if you have any suggestions for me.